# How to make web-mode handle HTML inside <script> element?

Tags: web-mode, script

I have  elements that contain various things. Some contain HTML; web-mode does not realize that so it messes up the indentation. Some contain CSS; same issue.

My first preference is, can I somehow tell web-mode what language is inside each  element? (I can mechanically intuit from the  attributes. I can do light Emacs hacking.

My second preference is, can I somehow tell web-mode just to not mess with any formatting inside a  element? At least then, after I manually get it formatted right, web-mode won't clobber it.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-LP5">
        <!-- need to tell web-mode this is HTML; otherwise it has no clue and indents like thi: -->
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>LP5 bootstrap</title>
        <style>
        @<LP5_GlobalCSS@>
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        @<LP5_1@>
        </body>
        </html>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can give some concrete examples, it might help people give you more concrete answers.

Comment: Not sure what part's unclear, but OK.

Comment: E.g. I don't know *when* web-mode "messes" in undesirable ways.  But based on your example, I think you might like to start with a bug report to the web-mode maintainer telling it that web-mode should be cautious when inside a `<script>` whose `type` is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the place (`web-mode-scan-elements`) in the source where it decides what mode to apply to a `<script>` element contents. It doesn't seem to allow for any hooks for custom types, but I think I can apply a patch there unless a better option appears.